# Как в WP ограничить количество за постов на странице, используя the_posts_pagination()?

Tags: wordpress

По умолчанию выводится 10 постов, остальное переносится на следующие страницы пагинации.
Как уменьшить до 9ти?

Comment: Настройка в админке

Comment: спасибо) думал всё сложнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант изменить переменную, отвечающую за дефолтное количество постов в цикле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если есть возможность изменять код, и количество постов нужно изменить только в одном месте, то можно сформировать свой запрос и указать параметр `posts_per_page` на нужное значение. Подробнее о получении постов "своими руками" можно прочитать [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_767)